# Python - multiple *args inside a tuple (is it possible at all?)

Tags: python, tuples, arguments, iteration

I am not sure if that is possible at all. I want when I create a tuple and iterate over it  multiple *args to be created.
For example:

```
alabama_state="Alabama","Montgomery","Mobile","Tuscaloosa","Dothan","Huntsville","Birmingham","Madison","Auburn","Phenix City"
state_name,capital,*metropolitan,*city=alabama_state
print(state_name)
print(capital)
print(metropolitan)
print(city)
```

I want `print(state_name)` to print **Alabama**, `print(capital)` to print **Montgomery**, `print(metropolitan)` to print everything from **Mobile** to **Huntsville** included and `print(city)` to print everything from **Birmingham** to the end. How can I include specific count in the *args. Didn't find useful info.

Comment: You can only have a spread variable at the beginning or end. How is it supposed to know how many to put in each of `metropolitan` and `city`?

Comment: This is what I am asking, is it possible at all to pass a specific number of arguements in the *args.

Comment: Alright, I understand that it is not possible.

Comment: @Barmar `a, *b, c = [1, 2, 3, 4]` works fine. One wildcard, at any position.

Comment: Right, I wasn't precise. You can only have one spread, it will get everything not matched by the other variables.

Comment: As per [PEP3132](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/#specification): _A tuple (or list) on the left side of a simple assignment (unpacking is not defined for augmented assignment) may contain **at most one** expression prepended with a single asterisk (which is henceforth called a “starred” expression, while the other expressions in the list are called “mandatory”). This designates a subexpression that will be assigned a list of all items from the iterable being unpacked that are not assigned to any of the mandatory expressions, or an empty list if there are no such items._

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) may be an option, but it is not readable enough:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> alabama_state = ("Alabama", "Montgomery", "Mobile", "Tuscaloosa", "Dothan",
...                  "Huntsville", "Birmingham", "Madison", "Auburn", "Phenix City")
>>> it = iter(alabama_state)
>>> [state_name, capital, *metropolitan], [*city] = islice(it, 6), it
>>> state_name, capital, metropolitan, city
('Alabama',
 'Montgomery',
 ['Mobile', 'Tuscaloosa', 'Dothan', 'Huntsville'],
 ['Birmingham', 'Madison', 'Auburn', 'Phenix City'])
```

Example of multiple `islice`:

```
>>> it = iter(range(10))
>>> [a, *b], [*c], [*d] = islice(it, 4), islice(it, 4), it
>>> a, b, c, d
(0, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with spread syntax. You can use slices to specify specific indexes.

```
state_name, capital, *rest = alabama_state
metropolitan, city = rest[:4], rest[4:]
```